# PHP no me recibe correctamente los datos

Tags: php7, dompdf

Estoy realizando un programa que me muestre los pedido que se han realizado dependiendo de una fecha elegida, o dependiendo del instructor que lo elija.

Para esto, uso DOMPDF. Al enviar los datos para que se me realice la consulta a la base de datos y generar los documentos (en este caso, sólo se envía la fecha), se me envían todas las fechas que existen. Es decir, si hay 2 fechas, la consulta me mostrará todos los pedidos en esas dos fechas, en vez de la que se eligió.

Aquí el formulario:

```
<?php
    $fecha=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pedidos GROUP BY fecha_pedido");
    $c_f=$fecha->num_rows;
    if ($c_f>=1) {
        while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($fecha)) {
            echo "<details class='fecha'>";
            echo "<summary>";
            echo $f['fecha_pedido'];
            $fechas=$f['fecha_pedido'];
            echo "</summary>";
            echo "<form action='reporte_pdf.php' method='post' class='enviar_fechas'>";
            echo "<input type='text' class='enviar_fecha' name='fecha_pedido' value='" . $fechas . "''>";
            echo "<button><img src='excel.png' class='excel'></button>";
            echo "</form>";
            $instructores=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM instructores, pedidos WHERE pedidos.doc_in=instructores.doc_in AND fecha_pedido='$fechas' GROUP BY nombres_in");
            while ($in=mysqli_fetch_array($instructores)) {
                echo "<details>"; 
                echo "<summary>";
                echo $in['nombres_in'] . " " . $in['apellidos_in'];
                echo "</summary>";
                $producto=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM instructores, pedidos, productos WHERE pedidos.doc_in=instructores.doc_in AND fecha_pedido='$fechas' AND pedidos.cod_prod=productos.cod_prod");
                while ($p=mysqli_fetch_array($producto)) {
                    echo "<table border='1'class='tabla'>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'><strong>" . $p['sibol_prod'] . "</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre comercial del producto.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['nombre_prod'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Calidad.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['calidad_prod'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Generalidades.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['generalidades_prod'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos generales.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['re_generales_prod'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['re_espe_prod'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Empaque y rotulado.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['empaque_prod'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $p['presentacion_producto'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th class='titulos'>Imagen de referencia.</th>";
                    echo "<td class='generalidades'><img src='" . $p['imagen_prod'] . "' id='referencia'></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                echo "</details>";
            }
            echo "</details>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<font id='no'>Aún no hay registros.</font>";
    }
    ?>
```

Y aquí se recibe y se genera el PDF:

```
<?php 
# Cargamos la librería dompdf.
require_once './dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
include('conexion.php');
$fecha_pedido=$_GET['fecha_pedido'];
# Contenido HTML del documento que queremos generar en PDF.
$html='
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Ejemplo de Documento en PDF.</title>
</head>
<body>';
$ver_pedidos=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pedidos");
while ($vp=mysqli_fetch_array($ver_pedidos)) {
    if (isset($vp['doc_in'])) {
        $pedidos_in=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pedidos, instructores, productos WHERE pedidos.doc_in=instructores.doc_in AND pedidos.cod_prod=productos.cod_prod AND pedidos.fecha_pedido='$fecha_pedido'");
        while ($pi=mysqli_fetch_array($pedidos_in)) {
            $html.='
            <table border="1"class="tabla">
            <caption><h1>' . $pi["nombres_in"] . ' ' . $pi["apellidos_in"] . '</h1></caption>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>' . $fecha_pedido . '</center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>
            <td class="generalidades"><strong>' . $pi["sibol_prod"] . '</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Nombre comercial del producto.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["nombre_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Calidad.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["calidad_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Generalidades.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["generalidades_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Requisitos generales.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["re_generales_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["re_espe_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Empaque y rotulado.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["empaque_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>
            <td class="generalidades">' . $pi["presentacion_prod"] . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="titulos">Imagen de referencia.</th>
            <td class="generalidades"><img src="' . $pi['imagen_prod'] . '" id="referencia"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>';
        }
    }elseif(isset($vp['doc_fun'])){
       //Aún no hay código aquí.
    }
}
$html.='
</body>
</html>';

# Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
$mipdf = new DOMPDF();

# Definimos el tamaño y orientación del papel que queremos.
# O por defecto cogerá el que está en el fichero de configuración.
$mipdf ->set_paper("A4", "portrait");

# Cargamos el contenido HTML.
$mipdf ->load_html(utf8_decode($html));

# Renderizamos el documento PDF.
$mipdf ->render();

# Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
$mipdf ->stream('' . $fecha_pedido . '.pdf');
?>
```

Y cuando el .php está normal, sin DOMPDF, sí me realiza la consulta correctamente:

```
    <?php
include('conexion.php');
$fecha_pedido=$_GET['fecha_pedido'];
$ver_pedidos=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pedidos");
while ($vp=mysqli_fetch_array($ver_pedidos)) {
    if (isset($vp['doc_in'])) {
        $pedidos_in=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pedidos, instructores, productos WHERE pedidos.doc_in=instructores.doc_in AND pedidos.cod_prod=productos.cod_prod AND pedidos.fecha_pedido='$fecha_pedido'");
        while ($pi=mysqli_fetch_array($pedidos_in)) {
            echo "<table border='1'class='tabla'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><strong>" . $i['sibol_prod'] . "</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre comercial del producto.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['nombre_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Calidad.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['calidad_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Generalidades.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['generalidades_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos generales.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_generales_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_espe_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Empaque y rotulado.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['empaque_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['presentacion_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Imagen de referencia.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><img src='" . $i['imagen_prod'] . "' id='referencia'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
        }
    }elseif(isset($vp['doc_fun'])){

    }
}
```

¿Alguién sabe cómo hago para que me haga una correcta recepción de datos?

```
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `instructores`
--

CREATE TABLE `instructores` (
  `doc_in` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombres_in` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos_in` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contrasena_in` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_prog` bigint(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `instructores`
--

INSERT INTO `instructores` (`doc_in`, `nombres_in`, `apellidos_in`, `contrasena_in`, `id_prog`) VALUES
(0, '', '', 'siga', 0),
(123456, 'Instructor', 'Prueba', 'siga', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `pedidos`
--

CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `id_pedido` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_pedido` date NOT NULL,
  `estado_pedido` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `presentacion_producto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `doc_in` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_fun` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_prod` bigint(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pedidos`
--

INSERT INTO `pedidos` (`id_pedido`, `fecha_pedido`, `estado_pedido`, `presentacion_producto`, `doc_in`, `doc_fun`, `cod_prod`) VALUES
(1, '2019-03-12', 'Sin observar', '1000 CC', 123456, NULL, 1),
(2, '2019-03-12', 'Sin Observar', 'Frasco de 1000 CC', 123456, NULL, 3),
(3, '2019-03-05', 'Sin Observar', '1000 CC', 123456, NULL, 5);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `productos`
--

CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `cod_prod` bigint(100) NOT NULL,
  `sibol_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `nombre_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `categoria_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `sub_categoria_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `calidad_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `generalidades_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `re_generales_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `re_espe_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `empaque_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `presentacion_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `imagen_prod` longtext NOT NULL,
  `id_prog` bigint(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `productos`
--

INSERT INTO `productos` (`cod_prod`, `sibol_prod`, `nombre_prod`, `categoria_prod`, `sub_categoria_prod`, `calidad_prod`, `generalidades_prod`, `re_generales_prod`, `re_espe_prod`, `empaque_prod`, `presentacion_prod`, `imagen_prod`, `id_prog`) VALUES
(1, 'Aceite Crudo de Oliva', 'Aceite de oliva', 'Ingredientes', 'Aceites', 'NTC 258', 'Aceite crudo de oliva, obtenido &uacute;nicamente del fruto del olivo (olea europaea l.), obtenidos por procedimientos mec&aacute;nicos de extracci&oacute;n o por otros medios f&iacute;sicos, en condiciones especiales de temperatura que no alteran su composici&oacute;n y separados de los residuos de materia prima e impurezas y que no han sido sometido a ning&uacute;n proceso qu&iacute;mico o f&iacute;sico diferente a los mencionados. Los aceites crudos de oliva, obtenidos por presi&oacute;n en fr&iacute;o o primer prensado, son aptos para el consumo humano directo, previa depuraci&oacute;n.', 'El aceite de oliva debe tener un aspecto limpio a 25 o c, tener sabor y olor caracter&iacute;stico y estar libre de rancidez. No deben contener sustancias extra&ntilde;as. No presentar mezcla con otros aceites y grasas.', 'El producto debe contener: Acidez libre (% &aacute;cido ol&eacute;ico), 1% M&aacute;ximo &iacute;ndice de Yodo 94, M&aacute;ximo &iacute;ndice de Bellier 17, M&aacute;ximo &iacute;ndice de saponificaci&oacute;n 196 M&aacute;ximo. El aceite crudo de oliva debe cumplir con los requisitos fisicoqu&iacute;micos y perfil de &aacute;cidos grasos establecidos en la NTC 258. Los residuos de plaguicidas no de beben exceder los l&iacute;mites m&aacute;ximos establecidos en la Resoluci&oacute;n 2906 de 2007, el Ministerio de la Protecci&oacute;n Social.', 'El producto se empacar&aacute; en recipientes impermeables, suficientemente inertes al producto que aseguren su conservaci&oacute;n. Los envases utilizados deben ser de primer uso. El rotulado debe cumplir con los requisitos establecidos en la Resoluci&oacute;n 5109 de 2005 del Ministerio de Protecci&oacute;n Social.', 'FRASCO * 1000 CC', 'null', 1),
 (3, 'Aceitunas de Mesa', 'Aceitunas', 'Ingredientes', 'Frutas', 'Cumplir con los requisitos establecidos en: Norma T&eacute;cnica Colombiana NTC 4842 â€“ Aceitunas de mesa Norma T&eacute;cnica Colombiana NTC 512&shy;1 â€“ Industrias Alimentarias. Rotulado o etiquetado. Parte 1. Norma General. Norma T&eacute;cnica Colombiana NTC 512&shy;2 â€“ Industrias Alimentarias. Rotulado o etiquetado. Parte 1. Rotulado nutricional de alimentos envasado', 'La aceituna es el fruto del olivo. El fruto es una drupa comestible, de tama&ntilde;o variable, con una sola semilla, hueso o coraz&oacute;n en su interior. El fruto del olivo puede cortarse en cualquiera de sus etapas, las aceitunas verdes son cortadas cuando el fruto no ha madurado y las aceitunas negras son cortadas cuando est&aacute;n maduras. Conforme el fruto del olivo madura, se vuelve de verde a rojo, a purpura, volvi&eacute;ndose finalmente negro.', 'Las aceitunas pueden adquirirse en las siguientes presentaciones: Enteras, deshuesadas, rellenas (con pimiento, cebolla, at&uacute;n, anchoa, salm&oacute;n, etc), saladas (cortadas en lonjas o gajos) Las aceitunas generalmente provienen de las variedades: Manzanilla Sevillana, Manzanilla Cacere&ntilde;a, Hojiblanca, Alore&ntilde;a, Gordal Sevillana, Verdial, Lechin y Picual. Las aceitunas podr&aacute;n estar en un medio de cobertura liquido como salmuera, vinagre o aceite.', 'La aceituna de mesa deber&aacute; cumplir con la totalidad de los requisitos establecidos en la NTC&shy;4842', 'El producto se deber&aacute; empacar en envases o empaques de material inocuo que asegure su conservaci&oacute;n o higiene durante su almacenamiento, transporte, expendio y uso. El rotulado deber&aacute; cumplir en su totalidad con lo establecido en las NTC&shy;512&shy;1 y NTC 512&shy;2', 'FRASCO * 450 GRAMOS ENCURTIDAS', 'null', 1),
(5, 'Vegetales Encurtidos', 'Alcaparras en Conserva', 'Ingredientes', 'Vegetales', 'NTC 4107. Resoluci&oacute;n 14712 del Ministerio de Salud.', 'Producto obtenido a partir de una o varias frutas, hortalizas o verduras enteras, en trozos o molidos, previamente curadas en salmuera o que hayan sufrido o no una transformaciÃƒÂ³n lÃƒÂ¡ctica, conservadas en un medio de cobertura adecuado. Los vegetales sanos y limpios cortados o enteros son envasados hermÃƒÂ©ticamente en un medio de cobertura apropiado (soluciÃƒÂ³n a base de sal o ÃƒÂ¡cido acÃƒÂ©tico o vinagre de origen vÃƒÂ­nico) y sometidos a tratamientos fÃƒÂ­sicos permitidos que garanticen su conservaciÃƒÂ³n. En el proceso de conserva los vegetales son sumergidos (marinados) en una soluciÃƒÂ³n de Sal, que fermenta por si solo o con la ayuda de un inoculo (microorganismo como Lactobacillusplantarum), el cual baja el pH y aumenta la acidez del mismo, con el objeto de poder extender su conservaciÃƒÂ³n. La caracterÃƒÂ­stica que permite la conservaciÃƒÂ³n es el medio ÃƒÂ¡cido del vinagre que posee un pH menor que 4.6 y es suficiente para eliminar la mayor parte de las necrobacterias. El este proceso permite conservar los alimentos durante dos meses en promedio. Se suele aÃƒÂ±adir a la marinada hierbas y sustancias antimicrobianas.', 'La alcaparra (Capparisspinosa) son los frutos (Alcaparrones) y las yemas o capullos florales que no se han abierto (Alcaparras) comestibles. En el proceso de conserva las alcaparras son sumergidas en una soluci&oacute;n de sal, que fermenta por si solo o con la ayuda de un inoculo, el cual baja el pH y aumenta la acidez del mismo, con el objeto de poder extender su conservaci&oacute;n. La caracter&iacute;stica que permite la conservaci&oacute;n es el medio &aacute;cido del vinagre que posee un pH menor que 4.6 y es suficiente para eliminar la mayor parte de las necrobacterias. Conserva en salmuera.', 'Por 100 gramos de alcaparras en conserva: Calor&iacute;as: 23 kilocal, Grasas monoins 0,1 gr., Prote&iacute;nas: 2,4 gr., Grasas poliinsat.: 0,3 gr., Colesterol: 0,0, Mg Calcio: 40 Mg., Grasas sats: 0,2 gr., Magnesio: 33 Mg., F&oacute;sforo: 10 Mg., Vitamina C: 4,3 Mg., Potasio: 40 Mg., Vitamina E: 0,9 Mg., Sodio: 2964,&shy; Mg., Vitamina A: 139 IU.', 'En envase de vidrio que conserve las caracter&iacute;sticas organol&eacute;pticas del producto. Rotulado con el nombre del producto, nombre del productor o empacador (marca comercial), fecha de empaque, fecha de vencimiento, lote de producci&oacute;n, peso neto El producto en su r&oacute;tulo debe cumplir con lo establecido en la Resoluci&oacute;n 5109 de 2005 del ministerio de la Protecci&oacute;n Social.', 'FRASCO * 200 GRAMOS ENCURTIDAS', 'null', 1);
```

Lo que necesito que me muestre en el PDF, es justo lo que aparece dentro del primer  que son las fechas.

Comment: te sugiero revisar si la consulta retorna resultados mediante el var_dump($pedidos_in); ..en donde intentas realizar tu pdf

Comment: Disculpa, pero... ¿Para qué me funcionaría?

Comment: Primero debes descartar lo mas evidente, es decir si estas recibiendo la fecha, si con dicha fecha hace la consulta.... y para mostrar la consulta es con var_dump... http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#1 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(25) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Esto me aparece

Comment: ¿Nos envías el SQL con algunos registros para poder reproducir el fallo? https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ya edité esa pregunta.

Comment: No localizo el SQL en la edición de la pregunta... :( Desde el phpMyAdmin opción Exportar

Comment: Ahora sí. No sé porqué no se subió ahorita.

Comment: Santiago, creo que ya sé que te está pasando: que has abierto varias preguntas y ésta es la tercera versión. Elimina las que sobran y edita correctamente la https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245922/no-se-me-env%C3%ADan-los-distintos-datos, o bueno, la que prefieras, pero deja sólo una

Comment: Señor David, debo decir que eres paciente y de buen manejo. Agradezco mucho eso. Es que mi tiempo es extremadamente limitado para entregar eso. Aún así, ya edité la pregunta mejor.

Comment: SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE fecha_pedido='$fecha_pedido'

Comment: Es select es para que me muestre en unos <details> todas las fechas posibles.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91124/discussion-between-david-and-santiago-correa-aguirre-sanmar).